What is the right way to add a git dependency that is a virtual workspace
I have a Rust library that depends on a secured***** git repo like so:
some-dependency = { git = ssh://secure-repo/project.git }

*  I've configured cargo with net.git-fetch-with-cli = true
The repo has been set up as a virtual workspace:
# Cargo.toml in the root of the repo

[workspace]
resolver = "2"
members = [
    "some-dependency",
    # other members
]

And my member crate is as vanilla as it can be:
[package]
name = "some-dependency"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

Now, according to the Cargo book, this should be working...but Cargo stubbornly insists:
error: no matching package named `some-dependency` found

First thing I've done is dig through the official docs, and then through the open issues on Rust's GitHub page, but found nothing helpful. Then I've decided to set up a test repo with the exact same structure, but without the root Cargo.toml file. And that worked!
I imagine that, for whatever reason, Cargo just doesn't traverse the rest of the repo after it stumbles upon the root Cargo.toml and determines that some-dependency is not defined in there.
Has anyone seen something like this? Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated
Update:
I've created another test setup with the same structure and relationships in GitHub and the dependency was resolved. I'm out of ideas as what this problem might be

"Then I've decided to set up a test repo with the exact same structure, but without the root Cargo.toml file. And that worked!" - does that mean you have a reproducible example with the exact same structure with a root Cargo.toml doesn't work but it should? Can you provide that? Cuz you are right that it should just work™ as long as the subcrate is listed as a member.

One other thing to try is to specify a commit hash in your git dependency to double-ensure Cargo is fetching what you expect it to.

@kmdreko the setup with the root Cargo.toml is the one I have to use. The other one I've created just to test my theory that the root Cargo.toml is somehow the culprit. As for providing it - sadly I can't, it's a private repo within my company.
I've tried specifying a rev = hash as you suggested but with the same result

Hmm, unfortunately I think your question is doomed without a reproducible example. It should just work. I just tried an ssh git dependency for Rocket's repo which has a virtual root Cargo.toml with even git-fetch-with-cli=true and it worked for me. Try it for yourself if you like: rocket = { git = "ssh://github.com/rwf2/Rocket.git", branch = "master" }.

OK, problem has been solved. For anyone ending up in the same situation:
TLDR:
The culprit was a swallowed (or simply wrong) error message in Cargo.
Gimme the spicy details
some-dependency depends on a crate, let's call it private-reg-dep, that's fetched from a private registry. The access to this registry I haven't got set up on my machine, so failing to resolve private-reg-dep somehow made Cargo report error: no matching package named 'some-dependency' found.

Interesting. You should file an issue with Cargo cuz that is definitely not a nice error if that was the problem.
